# How to pass guid to angular ng-init

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to pass the following value to angular ng-init method

```
ViewBag.payer = "921AC694-BA62-4388-AD92-282BD95526E1"

<input ng-model ="pid" ng-init="updatesubscriber(pid = @ViewBag.payer )"/>
```

I keep getting the following error:
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.11/$parse/syntax?p0=AC694&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B)%5D&p2=21&p3=updatesubscriber(921AC694-BA62-4388-AD92-282BD95526E1)&p4=AC694-BA62-4388-AD92-282BD95526E1)

It seems like angular doesnt like the hyphens in the payer string and probably evaluating the string as an expression..

How can I just pass the ViewBag.payer and prevent this error?

Comment: what is `updatesubscriber()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You nearly have it.  When your `<input>` is rendered server side `@ViewBag.payer` will be a guid.  But you want a string in JavaScript.  So, you just need to wrap quotes around it:

```
<input ng-model ="pid" ng-init="updatesubscriber(pid = '@ViewBag.payer' )"/>
```

Then, it should render as:

```
<input ng-model ="pid" ng-init="updatesubscriber(pid = '921AC694-BA62-4388-AD92-282BD95526E1' )"/>
```

JavaScript doesn't know how to evaluate a block of text that looks like `21AC694-BA62-4388-AD92-282BD95526E1`.